# Member reference base type 'std::vector<char> *[10]' is not a structure or union

Tags: c++, class, pointers, templates, vector

I have the following problem:
I´m trying to to some simple push in my class but its no working..

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>

 template <size_t B, size_t N, typename T = char>
 class Number
 {
   private:
     std::vector<T>* v[N];
     int toBase(int valor);

   public:
     Number(int valor);
     Number <B,N,T> suma(const Number<B,N,T>& sumando) const;
    //ostream& write(ostream& os)const;
 };

 template <size_t B, size_t N, typename T>
 Number<B,N,T>::Number(int valor)
 {
   toBase(valor);
 }


 template <size_t B, size_t N, typename T>
 int Number<B,N,T>::toBase(int valor)
 {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     int aux = valor % B;
     v.push_back(aux); // PROBLEM HERE
   }
 }

  template <size_t B, size_t N, typename T>
  Number<B,N,T> Number<B,N,T>::suma(const Number<B,N,T>& sumando) const
  {
    //sumando.toBase();
  }
```

The compiler says "member reference base type 'std::vector *[10]' is not a structure or union
    v.push_back(aux);"

I think the problem starts with my vector *v. Maybe i cant use push_back because its a pointer? I dont know..

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: That's an array of pointers to vectors of `T`. If you expect to do `v.push_back` it's clearly not the type you want to be using. It seems like you just wanted a `std::vector<T> v;`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `std::vector<T>* v[N];`?

Comment: I´m trying without the pointer but is says the same error.

Comment: I was trying to use the point because the compiler complains without it. It was complaining something about my vector was undefined or something like that. But now it doesnt..

Comment: toBase() has to separate each number of a hole number (if that makes sense). For example 7652 = 7, 6, 5, 2. And it has to storage it inside the vector v.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. Also, B, N and T are not very helpful in understanding your code and according to common coding guidelines they are names reserved for macros, as they are all uppercase.

Comment: You have an array of vectors, so need something like v[i].push_back(aux);

Comment: I´m so dumb.. I forgot the [i] lol. Nevermind guys thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're making this way more complicated than it needs to be and just confusing yourself. Change your class to this

```
 class Number
 {
   private:
     std::vector<char> v;
     int toBase(int valor);

   public:
     Number(int valor);
     Number suma(const Number& sumando) const;
    //ostream& write(ostream& os)const;
 };
```

You're trying to split a number into it's digits and put them in a vector. So just write a simple class with a vector like above. No templates or pointers or arrays are required for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I fixed it already. I forgot the [i] in the v. Anyways the exercise says you have to use templeta class so :/ .Thank you.

Comment: @Michalistico `std::vector<char>` is a template class. *Using* a template class is different from *defining* a template class. Maybe there's more to this exercise than you've said but if your problem really is to break an integer into it's digits, then defining a template, and all the other complexity you have in the code above, is not needed.

Comment: @Michalistico Thinking about it a bit more. Maybe the point is to abstract the notion of a digit, so a digit isn't necessarily a char. If that's the case then yes `template <size_t B, typename T = char> class Number` makes sense. But you still don't need the pointers and arrays that you are using, just a vector.